# How to fixed image when moving item in QGraphicsViewer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing an image viewer using pyqt.

I want the image to be fixed when the box moved.

However, the image is pushed when the box tries to reach the viewer's side like this.

[image: before box move]
[image: after box move]

It was implemented using QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, and QGraphicsitem.

This is part of main class

```
        self.scene_r = GraphicsScene()
        self.scene_r.addPixmap(pix_resized)
        self.resizedView.setScene(self.scene_r)
        self.resizedView.centerOn(128,128)
```

This is QGraphicScene Class

```
class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QGraphicsScene.__init__(self)
    rect_item = recItem(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100))
    rect_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
    rect_item.setZValue(1)
    rect_item.setPen(Qt.green)
    self.addItem(rect_item)
```

I tried to override mouseMoveEvent() of QGraphicsRectItem class, but it failed.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Sorry for posting an unkind question. Edited the question a little.

Answer (score 0):

That happens for two reasons:

1. Since you are making the item movable, you can move it freely, *anywhere* you want.
2. When the scene rectangle is smaller than the one visible in the view, the view tries to ensure that the whole scene rectangle stays visible, possibly by scrolling its contents.

Note that, unless explicitly set using `setSceneRect()` (on the scene or on the view, the results might differ), Qt automatically sets the scene rect implicitly to the bigger QRect that contains all visible graphics items.

There at least two possible solutions to your problem, which one to choose depends on what you need, and you can also decide to use both of them.

### Explicitly set the sceneRect

You can set the sceneRect to a specific rectangle, an item, or all existing items. Note that, while in your case it won't change much if you set the rectangle for the scene or the view, in more complex cases (for example, multiple views showing the same scene) the result might differ.

```
    # on the view
    self.setSceneRect(self.scene_r.itemsBoundingRect())
    # alternativaly, on the scene
    self.setSceneRect(self.itemsBoundingRect())
```

### Limit the area in which the item can be moved

In this case you can intercept the [itemChange](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) `ItemPositionChange` (note that the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag must be set) and return an adjusted value *before* it is actually applied:

```
class RecItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setFlags(self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemPositionChange:
            sceneRect = self.scene().sceneRect()
            newGeometry = self.boundingRect().translated(value)
            # the item pen must be taken into account
            halfPen = self.pen().width() / 2
            if value.x() < sceneRect.x():
                value.setX(sceneRect.x() + halfPen)
            if value.y() < sceneRect.y():
                value.setY(sceneRect.y() + halfPen)
            if newGeometry.right() + halfPen > sceneRect.right():
                value.setX(sceneRect.right() - newGeometry.width())
            if newGeometry.bottom() + halfPen > sceneRect.bottom():
                value.setY(sceneRect.bottom() - newGeometry.height())
            return value
        return super().itemChange(change, value)
```